# Is there any way to set a recursive environment variable in Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I have an apps directory in my dropbox - I'd like to be able to access all of them from the command line without having to set up loads and loads of path variables. Is there any way to set up a recursive path variable? I tried putting ** at the end - no joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use placeholders or anything like that in the `PATH` environment variable. It's just a concatenation of directories, no additional features.

So either add all of the app directories to the `PATH`environment variable or think about other ways to solve the problem. For example, you could add one directory to the `PATH` and place batch files named like the apps there that start the apps.

Comment: Fair do's. I'll probably run a job at startup or something to update the path variable

Comment: @mcintyre321 If I were going to be automatically modifying an environment variable, I think I would create my own separate variable and include that in `PATH`. That keeps me from messing up some other part of `PATH` that has nothing to do with my automation.

Answer (score 0):

Made an account for this 11 year old question.

```powershell
    $path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the exact path that needs to be recursively added to the PATH env:"
    $items = gci -Path $path -Recurse -Directory -name
    $nuPath = $env:Path
    $r = 0
    write-Host "Env started as $nuPath"
    foreach ($iitem in $items){
    $addpath = ($path + "\" + $iitem)
    $executabledir = $addpath + '\' + "*.exe"
    if(test-path $executabledir){
    Write-Host $addpath
    $regexAddPath = [regex]::Escape($addPath)
    $arrPath = $nuPath -split ';' | Where-Object {$_ -notMatch "^$regexAddPath\\?"}
    $nuPath = ($arrPath + $addPath) -join ';'
    ++$r
    }
    }
    $result = ($path + ";" + $nupath) -join ';'
    $temp = New-TemporaryFile
    $result.ToString() > $temp
    Start-Process notepad.exe -ArgumentList $temp.FullName
    
    $title    = 'WARNING'
    $question = "Your new environmental variable for PATH will be in the notepad window that popped up. are you sure you want to continue?"
    $choices  = '&Yes', '&No'
    
    $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
    if ($decision -eq 0 -and $r -gt 5) {
        $title    = 'Are you really sure?'
        $question = 'This is larger than 5 entries and this can ruin your day if you mess it up. Just doublechecking everything is OK'
        $choices  = '&Yes', '&No'
    
        $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
            if ($decision -eq 0) {
            $env:Path > $HOME\pathbkup.txt
            [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $result, "Machine")
            }
            else {
            Write-Host 'cancelled'
            }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'cancelled'
         }
    Remove-Item $temp
```